# Range of Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I have a list of 25 spots and I know Value #1 and Value #25. What is the best way to estimate the values in between:

Example:

## 1: 250,000

## 2

## 3

## 4

## 5

## 6

## 7

## 8

## 9

## 10

## 11

## 12

## 13

## 14

## 15

## 16

## 17

## 18

## 19

## 20

## 21

## 22

## 23

## 24

## 25: 38,400

I want to estimate what the range of numbers would be for spots #2-#24. Any formula would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the values have any constraints on them? And how do you measure "best"? The "easiest" and "most reasonable" thing I can think of is just linear interpolation where the numbers decrease by a constant difference from 250000 to 38000.

Comment: I would say the values get more competitive towards the top. So it should be linear because it would be easier to move from 25 to 24 but it would be more difficult to move from 2 to 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chris That explanation is explicitly *not* linear if "more difficult" means "bigger difference".

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of ways to interpolate values.

The simplest is a linear interpolation: constant difference between steps.  You have $25 - 1 = 24$ intervals.  The total difference is $250000 - 38400 = 211600$, so you'd want your step size to be

$$\frac{211600}{24} \approx 8816.67.$$

But you might want another way to fill them in, depending on your application.